# Can a morphologically singular collective noun be syntactically plural?

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax, plural, agreement

In English the noun "family" is singular but it means a group (of people).
Syntactically it can be singular or plural: one can say "the family is/are…" with either choice.
Can this kind of thing happen in Latin at all?
Are there nouns which are morphologically singular but can take a plural syntactical role?

To give a concrete example: if I want to say that all my family members are Finns, can I say *tota mea familia Finni sunt*?
I have never seen this, and I would like to know whether anyone else has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allen & Greenough, *New Latin grammar*, states (§317, d):

> A collective noun commonly takes a verb in the singular; but the plural is often found with collective nouns when *individuals* are though of...

The corresponding rule in Gildersleeve & Lodge, *Latin grammar*, states (§211, Remark 1, a):

> Substantives of multitude often take the predicate in the Plural: **pars**, *part*; **vis** (*power*), *quantity*; **multitudo**, *crowd*; organized bodies more rarely.

Nouns such as *familia* in your question would fall under the category of 'organized bodies,' I suppose, and should be somewhat rare, according to G&L.

Here are some examples (culled from both books):

> **pars** ex pacatis praedas **agebant** [Sallust, *Bellum iugurthinum* 32]
>
> nam cum tanta **multitudo** lapides ac tela **conicerent**, in muro consistendi potestas erat nulli [Caesar, *De bello gallico* 2.6]
>
> ita Crotone excessum est deductique Crotoniatae ad mare naues conscendunt; Locros omnis **multitudo** **abeunt** [Livy, *Ab urbe condita* 24.3.15]
>
> simul ex minoribus navibus magna **vis** eminus missa telorum multa nostris de improviso imprudentibus atque inpeditis vulnera **inferebant** [Caesar, *De bello civili* 2.6.3]

A&G goes on to note (Note 1) that 'the point of view may change in the course of a sentence.' The example given is Caesar BG 1.15, where *equitatus* is referred to by a singular relative pronoun in one of the sentence's relative clause but by a plural pronoun + plural verb in the other. This example is notable because it doesn't involve a 'substantive of multitude' but an 'organized body' (to use G&L's terminology), and so is closest to your question about *familia*:

> idem facit Caesar **equitatumque** omnem, ad numerum quattuor milium, **quem** ex omni provincia et Haeduis atque eorum sociis coactum habebat, praemittit, **qui videant** quas in partes hostes iter faciant.

Furthermore, A&G 317, e and Note point out that singular pronouns such as *quisque*, *unus quisque*, *uterque*, and the phrases *alius...alium* and *alter...alterum*, 'very often' have a plural verb. (However, it's the opinion of the authors that these singular pronouns 'may be considered as in partitive apposition with a plural subject implied.') G&L (*loc. cit.*) includes *nemo* in the list of such pronouns, but also notes that their use with a plural verb occurs 'also, but not often.' So the two books disagree about how common this is.

> dum mi abstineant invidere, sibi **quisque** **habeant** quod suom est [Plautus, *Curculio* 180]
>
> eodemque die **uterque** eorum ex castris stativis a flumine Apso exercitum **educunt**, Pompeius clam et noctu, Caesar palam atque interdiu [Caesar, BC 3.30.3]

As to your concrete question about *familia*, the only example I could find of *familia* with a plural verb is in Phaedrus (*Fabulae aesopiae* 3.10.24), where the reference is – as I suspected it would be (though I expected to turn up more such examples) – to the collective group of household slaves specifically, not to family members in our sense of the term:

> dum **quaerunt** lumen, dum **concursant** **familia**,
> irae furentis impetum non sustinens
> ad lectum vadit, temptat in tenebris caput.

Still, if you wanted to use *familia* with a plural verb, you would have one ancient source to back up your choice, even if you're using the noun in a more limited sense.

(Personally, I think the proper translation of 'All my family members are Finns' is something like *mea domus tota Finnica est* or *meum genus totum Finnicum est* or even *omnes mei Finni sunt*.)

Comment: Many thanks! This is a very thorough and useful answer. (I agree with your parenthetical final paragraph, but I wanted to include a concrete example in the question to avoid misunderstandings.)

Comment: It is not an ancient source, but in the Book "Julia" by Reed, he seem to use plural verb with familia  (or I'm missing something): "Sed fleverunt familia et flevit Triptolemus"